# How to do a complex SQL selection based upon a set of hierarchical rules?

Tags: sql, selection, hierarchical

Here is what I have:

T1 is a big selection of IDs and totals from a complex SQL. TA, PF and BL are 3 different tables for holding different address information.

In order to get the right address for each ID in T1, there is a set of 3 hierarchical rules to follow:

TA is the 1st address table to check for a row's existence with a T1.ID. If a row exists in TA, get the address and ignore checking table PF and BL.

PF is the 2nd address table to check if I get nothing returned from TA with a T1.ID. If a row exists in PF, get the address and ignore checking table BL.

BL is the 3rd address table to check if I get nothing returned from PF with a T1.ID, If a row exists in BL, get the address.

Right now I have code like the following and it runs for a LONG time even separately without using UNION!!! How can I write this logic in an efficient way? Please Help!

```
select T1.ID, TA.ADDRESS,T1.TOTALS
from T1, TA
where T1.ID = TA.ID and TA.ADDRESS like "1"

UNION

select T1.ID, PF.ADDRESS,T1.TOTALS
from T1, PF
where T1.ID = PF.ID and PF.ADDRESS like "2"
and not exists(select 1
                from TA
               where TA.ID = T1.ID
                 and TA.ADDRESS like "1")
UNION

select T1.ID, BL.ADDRESS, T1.TOTALS
from T1, BL
where T1.ID = BL.ID and BL.ADDRESS like "3"
and not exists(select 1
                from TA
               where TA.ID = T1.ID
                 and TA.ADDRESS like "1")
and not exists(select 1
                from PF
               where PF.ID = T1.ID
                 and PF.ADDRESS like "2")
```

Comment: Hi @tweetybird.  You may have noticed that I formatted your post.  The gist of Stack Overflow is that if you want to make code appear as code, put at least 4 spaces in front of it.  As far as your question goes, given how often I see the word "if" in your narrative, are you familiar with the sql function coalesce()?  Most databases support it.  Your's might but it's hard to tell because you didn't identify it (hint hint)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change `ADDRESS like "1"` to `ADDRESS = "1"`. In this case the DB Engine will be able to use index on ADDRESS (if one exists).

Second, you can get rid of `not exist` if you do this:

```
select T1.ID, TA.ADDRESS,T1.TOTALS, TA.ADDRESS
from T1, TA
where T1.ID = TA.ID and TA.ADDRESS like "1"

UNION

select T1.ID, PF.ADDRESS,T1.TOTALS, PF.ADDRESS
from T1, PF
where T1.ID = PF.ID and PF.ADDRESS like "2"

UNION

select T1.ID, BL.ADDRESS, T1.TOTALS, BL.ADDRESS
from T1, BL
where T1.ID = BL.ID and BL.ADDRESS like "3"

ORDER BY 4
```

As you can see in the above query I have included the `ADDRESS` to the list of selected columns and ordered by this column. I have removed `not exist` from the queries. This means that all addresses will be selected, ordered by the level of preference

Now, you have two options: Either use the application to grab only the first row, ignoring other, or, if you can't modify the application code then you need to use either TOP (for SQL Server), LIMIT (for MySql), ROW_NUM (for Oracle) technique to grab first n rows. You have not tagged the RDBMS you use, so, please find out yourself

Comment: Thank you @Dan Bracuk. I just turned in the results due to deadline but I will try your method later.